# How should I draw the semi cylinder in the sketch?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How should I draw the semi cylinder in the sketch?

https://postimg.org/image/lhl7x7t33/

https://postimg.org/image/6mwmj1ji7/

So, I don't know how to show that there is a semi cylinder in the horizontal view. (lower view)

Answer (score 2):

The break out areas of the circle is what needs to be represented. It will be drawn with dotted line because it will be hidden in your view. No other call outs will need to be made.

If your circle was off center from the break out points, and the side walls of the bore were intact, then you would draw the break out points AND the side walls, both in hidden dotted lines.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine since you mention what would happen if it didn't break out on the middle.

Comment: @Jethro H Could you explain what break out points are? I am not English so I don't understand. I now have put a dotted horizontal line at the upper right view for the half circle.

Comment: alright, I see what you are after now.

Comment: your upper right view will have just 1 dotted line showing the bottom of the through bore. your bottom view also needs 2 dotted lines showing where the bore breaks the plane of the top view.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would show it if it was a rectangle, dotted lines.  It's literally just a hidden feature, the view above it will show that it's a semicircle, this bottom view will show that extends all the way through the part.